# IWin32Window in C#?

Tags: c#

How do i use this to create a tooltip?

Ive tried looking through all articles in MSDN website but i just cannot get my head round it.

Thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly is it you want to do? For most purposes, you just add a `Tooltip` and set values against controls. Some controls provide their own tool-tip (and mechanism to set the text).

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    { // example code only... doesn't do cleanup
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Button btn = new Button();
        Form form = new Form();
        form.Controls.Add(btn);
        ToolTip ttip = new ToolTip();
        ttip.SetToolTip(btn, "Hello world");
        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

---

re the comment; then just something like:

```
form.Shown += delegate {
    ttip.Show("hi", form, 0,0, 3000);
};
```

(where `form` could be the form, "`this`", or any control)

Comment: I just want to show a tooltip for now that jus shows some text nothing fancy, i wana hard code the text in and show it onload.

Comment: The code before thats in C# does the same as this but i dont think this will actually show the tooltip, well didnt when i last tried it

Comment: Ohhhh so the iWin32 thing is just any control on the form? Including the form?

Comment: Yes - all controls provide a windows handle - i.e. an IWin32Window

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you're looking for?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288412(VS.71).aspx)  You shouldn't need to use interop for tooltips.

Comment: I tried this but to actually show the tooltip you need to use the IWin32Window thing because its one of the parameters needed to show the object.

Thanks though :)